# C# - Симуляция ввода текста пользователем в консольное приложение

Tags: c#

Задача такова, на фоне работает консольное приложение, мое приложение при нажатии на кнопку симулирует ввод текста в этом консольном приложении, то есть по факту команду в консоль отправляет не пользователь а программа.

Пример: Пользователь нажал кнопку "Вывести текст test", и в работающем приложении напечаталась команда "echo test" и отправилась.
(Это не обязательно cmd, может быть любое другое консольное приложение)

Вопрос - Как это возможно реализовать и возможно ли?

Comment: Через winapi, это на C/C++ или через pinvoke, но там вызываемых функций будет много, рекомендую пересесть на C++ и использовать в коде собственную библиотеку. Или смотреть как все это внедрить на https://pinvoke.net

Comment: @NewView, есть такая вещь, называется именованные каналы. Создать два приложения по типу клиент-сервер: консольное на прослушку, гуишное - на посыл. Явного использования WinAPI при этом не требуется

Comment: У пайпов куча недостатков, связанных с блокировками, но можно и через них. Не универсально правда, но область применения безусловно есть и для такого решения. Куда уж проще `PostMessage(..,SET_TEXT,..)`

Comment: перенаправить поток ввода при запуске приложения не вариант?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посылает текст textToSend на апликуху с ЗАГОЛОВКОМ процесса  processTitle.
Не важно оно консольное или WinForm.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public void SendTextToProcess(string processTitle, string textToSend)
{
    IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
    for (int i = 0; (i < 10) && (zero == IntPtr.Zero); i++)//Пытается найти окно
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        zero = FindWindow(null, processTitle);
    }
    if (zero != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(zero);//делает окно активным (например консоли)
        SendKeys.SendWait(textToSend);//посылает нужные нажатия клавиш
        SendKeys.Flush();
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
SendTextToProcess("Untitled - Notepad", "hello World{ENTER}Tab{TAB}{TAB}test{TAB}{TAB}finished{ENTER}");
```

Напечатает в открытом пустом блокноте:

```
hello World
Tab     test        finished
```

Если же для тебя важно отправлять месаджи именно в бекграунде (без того что бы делать окно активным), то тебе нужно смотреть в сторону [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) и [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx). Есть вот такая вот библиотека https://github.com/EasyAsABC123/Keyboard которая реализует этот функционал.

Важный нюанс работы с SendMessage описан вот в этой теме: [Напечатать символ в неактивное окно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935530/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE/935567#935567)