# Напечатать символ в неактивное окно?

Tags: c#

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam);
public static void Pac()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    var dHWnd = FindWindow(null, "Открыть");
    SendMessage(dHWnd, 0x0102, 0x41);
}
```

Пробовал так - не работает. Хотя HWnd ненулевой возвращает.

Comment: Если вы хотите заполнить EDIT - то будет проще сделать GetWindowText и SetWindowText. Но... всеравно нужно правильно HANDLE указать. Скачайте старенькую утилиту `Spy.exe` которая играется окнами, и поиграйте ею с окнами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinApi/винапи отправка нажатий на клавиатуру.

В случае с Foreground окном достаточно и IntPtr самого окна.

Но в случае Background окна этого недостаточно. Нужно искать IntPtr поля окна, а не самого окна. А потом уже в него делать SendMessage();

Соответственно это и есть причиной неудачи.

```
using Keyboard;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);


        const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("notepad.exe");

            Thread.Sleep(5000);//на время этого ожидания сделай другое окно активным

            var dialogHWnd = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");

            IntPtr notepadTextbox = FindWindowEx(dialogHWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);

            SendMessage(notepadTextbox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "This is the new Text!!! прапрао");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Да. IntPtr поля ввода окна (т.е. самого Edit).

Comment: `PostMessage` - асинхронно отправлять, с СендМесаг может и не получиться, иногда сообщения не доходят. Самое забавное, что если отправлять в режиме открытого дебагера, то и СендМесаг работает без сбоев. А в живом коде, не успевает отправить, судя по всему.

Comment: И ещё, если приложение свернуть в трей, ничего не выйдет,  надо его сперва развернуть.

Comment: @NewView а чем технически отличается minimized от сворачивания в трей? Я как-то думал что сворачивание в трей это minimized  + hide с панели + создание иконки в трее.

Comment: Там кажется обрезается очередь принимаемых сообщений, зависит от автора, в общем, при сворачивании проверяет например WM_PAINT или нет. Но как правило - нет.

Comment: полезные замечания автору, а мне просто интересные :) Спасибо

Comment: Вот примерчик как с этим бороться https://github.com/ClnViewer/GameDev/blob/5f7278d8f984b66b43408dc20d53354d2416b3e1/Wnd.cpp#L56 :)

Comment: @Andrew а как в игру передать нажатие клавиш ?

Comment: @АндрейReyz  Ищется по "c# global keypress event". Например:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C Но в даном случае игра будет активной на экране и будут просто имитироваться нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре

Comment: @Andrew можно как то без активного окна передавать значение игру ?

Comment: Пробуй смотреть в сторону SendMessage. Как раз в этом ответе.