# Подскажите ,как скрывать и развернуть сторонний процесс ( например notepad++, wordpad и так далее) C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, form

Подскажите ,как скрывать и развернуть сторонний  процесс  (например: notepad++, wordpad и так далее) C#? Буду очень благодарен за помощь)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0

Comment: Уточните, что значит скрывать и развернуть? Имеете ввиду минимизировать окно?

Comment: Вероятно дубликат вопроса: [C# - Симуляция ввода текста пользователем в консольное приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909307/c-%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) там рассматривалась активизация окна и печать в него. По аналогу можно сделать и минимизацию окна.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Например есть две кнопки и два процесса(то есть у первой ворпад , у второй нотпад).Я создал процесс под каждую кнопку , запускается приложение через process start. И при нажатие на другую кнопку у меня первый процесс убивается и второй появляется. Вопрос наверное не правильно поставил. Как сделать параллельную работу Этих двух приложений по нажатию кнопки, чтоб при нажатие не убивался прошлый процесс , а просто переключался на другой  ?

Comment: У процесса есть свойство MainWindowHandle, в библиотеках есть функции для переключения на окно по его хендлу, нужно их найти и импортировать через DllImport, если вкратце. Т.к. кода у вас нет никакого то и пример писать не особо вижу смысла

Comment: Вот так я и создаю и запускаю процесс

Comment: `Process p1 = Process.Start($@"path");
                p1.WaitForInputIdle();
                Thread.Sleep(2000); //sleep
                SetParent(p1.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
                SetWindowLong(p1.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
                MoveWindow(p1.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);`

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Спасибо за объяснение)