# C# WPF: Как программно нажать сочетание клавиш клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF-приложении есть метод `Test()`, который вызывается при нажатии сочетания клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

**Вызов метода работает, так как в консоль выводится строка `test`, из первой строки метода.**

---

Метод должен программно нажимать сочетание клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, выделяя тем самым текст в поле любом ввода, но этого не происходит.

**Я пробовал 2 способа:**

---

**Первый:** Метод `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait()`, принимающий строку, где `^` - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - в соответствии с [**документацией**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

```cs
private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    SendKeys.SendWait("^A");
}
```

Однако при этом нажатия не происходит.

---

**Второй:** Реализация через `user32.dll`, решение взято [**отсюда**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11403269/14519908):

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
{
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    if (up)
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
    else
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
}

private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, up: false);
    PressKey(Keys.A, up: false);
    PressKey(Keys.A, up: true);
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, up: true);
}
```

Но и в этом случае ничего не происходит.

---

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: мож поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/909423/186752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keybd_event` является устаревшим методом Win API, актуальным является `SendInput`. Для первого вам пришлось бы реализовать ручную паузу типа `Thread.Sleep(50)` между нажатием и отпусканием клавиш, тогда бы не всегда, но сработало. Но есть способ получше.

На самом деле есть NuGet пакет **InputSimulator**, он всё это умеет, просто установите его и используйте для вывода клавишь. Внутри себя он использует тот же `SendInput`, но у меня уже есть своя готовая реализация того метода, который вам нужен. `SendInput` кстати поддерживает и клавиатурную и мышиную симуляцию.

**Win API**

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [Flags]
    public enum KeyboardFlags : uint
    {
        None = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001 (If specified, the scan code was preceded by a prefix byte that has the value 0xE0 (224).)
        /// </summary>
        ExtendedKey = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002 (If specified, the key is being released. If not specified, the key is being pressed.)
        /// </summary>
        KeyUp = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004 (If specified, wScan identifies the key and wVk is ignored.)
        /// </summary>
        Unicode = 4,

        /// <summary>
        /// KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008 (Windows 2000/XP: If specified, the system synthesizes a VK_PACKET keystroke. The wVk parameter must be zero. This flag can only be combined with the KEYEVENTF_KEYUP flag. For more information, see the Remarks section.)
        /// </summary>
        ScanCode = 8,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MouseFlags : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that movement occurred.
        /// </summary>
        Move = 0x0001,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the left button was pressed.
        /// </summary>
        LeftDown = 0x0002,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the left button was released.
        /// </summary>
        LeftUp = 0x0004,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the right button was pressed.
        /// </summary>
        RightDown = 0x0008,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the right button was released.
        /// </summary>
        RightUp = 0x0010,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the middle button was pressed.
        /// </summary>
        MiddleDown = 0x0020,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the middle button was released.
        /// </summary>
        MiddleUp = 0x0040,

        /// <summary>
        /// Windows 2000/XP: Specifies that an X button was pressed.
        /// </summary>
        XDown = 0x0080,

        /// <summary>
        /// Windows 2000/XP: Specifies that an X button was released.
        /// </summary>
        XUp = 0x0100,

        /// <summary>
        /// Windows NT/2000/XP: Specifies that the wheel was moved, if the mouse has a wheel. The amount of movement is specified in mouseData. 
        /// </summary>
        VerticalWheel = 0x0800,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the wheel was moved horizontally, if the mouse has a wheel. The amount of movement is specified in mouseData. Windows 2000/XP:  Not supported.
        /// </summary>
        HorizontalWheel = 0x1000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Windows 2000/XP: Maps coordinates to the entire desktop. Must be used with MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE.
        /// </summary>
        VirtualDesk = 0x4000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies that the dx and dy members contain normalized absolute coordinates. If the flag is not set, dxand dy contain relative data (the change in position since the last reported position). This flag can be set, or not set, regardless of what kind of mouse or other pointing device, if any, is connected to the system. For further information about relative mouse motion, see the following Remarks section.
        /// </summary>
        Absolute = 0x8000,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort virtualKey;
        public ushort scanCode;
        public KeyboardFlags flags;
        public uint timeStamp;
        public IntPtr extraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int deltaX;
        public int deltaY;
        public uint mouseData;
        public MouseFlags flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr extraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint message;
        public ushort wParamL;
        public ushort wParamH;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct InputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MOUSEINPUT mouse;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT keyboard;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hardware;
    }
    public enum InputType : int
    {
        Mouse = 0,
        Keyboard = 1,
        Hardware = 2
    }
    public struct INPUT
    {
        public InputType type;
        public InputUnion union;
    }

    public static int SizeOfInput { get; } = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT));

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SendInput(int nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
}
```

Теперь можно написать вот такой метод

```
public static void ModifiedKeyStroke(Key key, ModifierKeys modifiers = ModifierKeys.None)
{
    static NativeMethods.INPUT BuildINPUT(Key k, NativeMethods.KeyboardFlags flags) => new NativeMethods.INPUT
    {
        type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard,
        union = new NativeMethods.InputUnion { keyboard = new NativeMethods.KEYBDINPUT { virtualKey = (ushort)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(k), scanCode = 0, flags = flags, timeStamp = 0, extraInfo = IntPtr.Zero } }
    };
    List<Key> keys = new List<Key>();
    if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control)) keys.Add(Key.LeftCtrl);
    if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt)) keys.Add(Key.LeftAlt);
    if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift)) keys.Add(Key.LeftShift);
    if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Windows)) keys.Add(Key.LWin);
    keys.Add(key);
    NativeMethods.INPUT[] inputs = new NativeMethods.INPUT[keys.Count * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = BuildINPUT(keys[i], NativeMethods.KeyboardFlags.None);
        inputs[^(i + 1)] = BuildINPUT(keys[i], NativeMethods.KeyboardFlags.KeyUp);
    }
    _ = NativeMethods.SendInput(inputs.Length, inputs, NativeMethods.SizeOfInput);
}
```

Выглядит страшно, но так решили Microsoft сделать нечно монструозное. Зато работает безотказно.

**Как использовать**

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

```
ModifiedKeyStroke(Key.C, ModifierKeys.Control);
```

<kbd>Ctrl+Shit+Esc</kbd>

```
ModifiedKeyStroke(Key.Escape, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift);
```

<kbd>F</kbd>

```
ModifiedKeyStroke(Key.F);
```

---

Есть кстати системное ограничение на использование некоторых комбинаций, например с использованием `ModifierKeys.Windows` и еще типа `Ctrl+Alt+Del`, это запрещает сценарии, где например какое-то приложение смогло бы без вашего ведома сменить вам пароль на систему и прочие опасные штуки. Это не обойти, просто если что-то не срабатывает, то в первую очередь убедитесь, что это не ограничено системой защиты Windows.

Comment: Как способ программного нажатия клавиш - это сработало, однако не работает корректно именно при вызове с горячих клавиш `ALT+G`. Точнее, все равно приходится выставлять задержку, поскольку клавиша `ALT` отпускается не сразу и получается комбинация `CTRL+ALT+A`. Есть полный код: https://pastebin.com/4yEHK4v0

Comment: Мне дали еще один ответ на английской версии: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987297/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-programmatically-press-a-keyboard-button/71988357#71988357, где подробно расписали как эту проблему решить, но из этого решения появилась еще одна.

Comment: @denisnumb дело в том, что помимо работы операционной системы по нажатию клавиш, есть еще система передачи сообщений Windows, а если ваше приложение попадает первым в цепочке передачи, то нужно, чтобы UI поток был свободным на момент проксирования сообщения, то есть `Thread.Sleep()` использовать категорически нельзя, используйте асинхронное ожидание `await Task.Delay()`, пометив метод как `async` и всё заработает.

Comment: Понял, с задержкой работает. Но если не отпустить клавишу `ALT` в течение 100 мс., то текст не выделится (опять же, из-за лишней нажатой клавиши `ALT` в комбинации). Есть ли какой-то способ избежать этого не выстраивая сложные схемы как в [ответе на англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987297/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-programmatically-press-a-keyboard-button/71988357#71988357)? Например просто "поднять" все нажатые клавиши клавиатуры?

Comment: @denisnumb если у вас что-то работает не так как надо, надо фиксить баги в коде, а не ставить диагноз "безнадежно, нужен костыль". То что у вас выше в коде - это смесь из непонятно чего. Задайте другой конекретный вопрос, выложите туда код, объясните проблему. Если Alt залипает, значит вы его забыли отпустить. Или вообще наделали других ошибок в коде.

Comment: Да, пожалуй я задам новый вопрос. На этот дан исчерпывающий ответ, спасибо :)