# C#: Как имитировать ввод текста с клавиатуры не только внутри приложения?

Tags: c#

Необходимо написать метод, принимающий строку в виде любого текста, который в результате должен написать этот текст в любое поле ввода имитируя ввод с клавиатуры.

Недавно я уже задавал [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403263/c-wpf-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B), но там речь была о нажатии конкретных клавиш клавиатуры, коды для которых уже имеются в виде `enum`. Здесь же речь идет вообще о любых символах - то есть должен имитироваться ввод подобного текста: "³⁸⁽⋜" и т.п.

---

**Что я пробовал:**

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("³⁸⁽⋜");
```

Это работает только для полей ввода в приложении, т.к. `Keyboard` фокусируется только на ни х. *(Решение взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c))*

```cs
var text = "³⁸⁽⋜";
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
var routedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent;

target.RaiseEvent(
  new TextCompositionEventArgs(
    InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice,
    new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, text))
  { RoutedEvent = routedEvent }
);
```

Comment: А нельзя просто скопировать текст в буфер обмена и вставить его, где это нужно будет? (Clipboard) У меня создается впечатление, что я не совсем правильно вас понял

Comment: Так как вам нужно отправлять символы юникода, то эмуляция нажатия клавиш с клавиатуры вам не подойдет. Вы же не можете эти смайлики ввести просто нажимая кнопки на клаве, так? Самое простое решение - буфер обмена, отправляете туда текст и эмулируете нажатие `Ctrl+V`.

Comment: @Frehzy - здОрово, оригинальное решение! И никакой возни с юникодом: кто может - понимает его, а кто не может - тот как то по своему воспринимает...

Comment: @S.H. это не просто нормальное, это единственное рабочее из тех что знаю, а я давно с буфером дружу.

Comment: @aepot мне приходило в голову это решение. Разве это будет правильно постоянно забивать буфер обмена? Просто, например в `python` есть библиотека `keyboard`, у которой есть метод `write()`, принимающий и пишущий любой текст. Вот, `936 строка`: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py

Comment: А вы проверяли, он работает со всем приложениями? Что по поводу буфера, можно его сбэкапить перед вводом туда своих данных, а после того как вставка отработает, восстановить бэкап. Задача не суперпростая, но я решил.

Comment: Хотя, вот решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/22308727/12888024 через `SendInput`. В вашем случае эту строку надо просто отправить посимвольно, с флагом KEYEVENTF_UNICODE

Comment: @aepot - строго говоря, можно ввести символы юникода с клавиатуры, но это "нечестный способ": через ALT. Нажимаем ALT, удерживаем его, в правой части на цифровой части клавиатуры (с включенным нумлоком) набираем что то вроде 0174 - и отпускаем альт. Но, я думаю, этот способ Вам знаком :-)

Comment: @S.H. это не исмволы юникода, а альт-коды https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: @aepot - да, точно; я прочитал еще про такой способ: печатаем в Ворде (ну, я проверял в ворде) код символа цифрами, например, 2764, потом нажимаем ALT и не отпуская его - X (по русски - ALT+X). И в этот момент происходит магия: код превращается в юникод - символ! :-)

Comment: Вспомнил, почему `SendInput` мне в свое время не подошел. Мне нужно было в визуальный редактор HTML вставлять фрагменты верстки именно как HTML, а на такое способен оказался только буфер обмена. Поэтому для просто текстовых полей таки `SendInput` вполне подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно эмулировать ввод с помощью того же `SendInput`, на базе структур из [прошлого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1403446/373567).

```
public static void SendStringInput(string text)
{
    static NativeMethods.INPUT BuildINPUT(char c) => new NativeMethods.INPUT
    {
        type = NativeMethods.InputType.Keyboard,
        union = new NativeMethods.InputUnion { keyboard = new NativeMethods.KEYBDINPUT { virtualKey = 0, scanCode = (ushort)c, flags = NativeMethods.KeyboardFlags.Unicode, timeStamp = 0, extraInfo = IntPtr.Zero } }
    };
    NativeMethods.INPUT[] inputs = new NativeMethods.INPUT[text.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = BuildINPUT(text[i]);
    }
    _ = NativeMethods.SendInput(inputs.Length, inputs, NativeMethods.SizeOfInput);
}
```