# Отслеживание изменения содержимого буфера обмена

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> глобальный HotKey а-ля <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> со своим обработчиком. Отслеживать нажатие хоткеев - есть такой класс, а вот как по нажатию этого хоткея копировалось в буфер все что выделено (текст например) во внешних приложениях?

То есть, читаю pdf-ку, выделяю нужный мне текст, нажимаю хоткей (свой), выделенный текст копируется в буфер, дальше я с ним провожу свои манипуляции.

Может как-то можно подписаться на изменение содержимого буфера?

Comment: Немного по-другому делается, регистрируете например Ctrl+1, по сработке симулируете Ctrl+C, после чего читаете буфер, производите изменения в данных, затем заносите в буфер измененные данные, затим симулируете Ctrl+V. Выглядит так как текст в редакторе просто заменяется, или вам не это надо?

Comment: Если вопрос только про то, можно ли технически отслеживать изменение буфера - можно, за это отвечает Windows сообщение WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD или WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE. Какое использовать, зависит от того, какую минимальюную винду вы хотите поддерживать. Первое совместимо по-моему даже с Win95, второе работает начиная с Win Vista. Реализовать проще именно второе. Вам какое?

Comment: Переходите на UWP, там есть событие [Clipboard.ContentChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.contentchanged?view=winrt-22621) (шутка)

Comment: Я когда впервые столкнулся с подобной задачей, просто опрашивал буфер обмена по таймеру. Работает прекрасно, систему не напрягает. Но лучше, конечно, использовать WinAPI, как предлагает aepot.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov сам до сегодняшнего дня в своих тулзах сидел на `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`, вот по случаю переписал на `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`. :)

Comment: Вот вопрос как эмулировать нажатие Ctrl+C? Причем это же надо эмулировать в сторонних приложениях. Думаю мне как раз подойдет этот способ с использованием своего хоткея.

Comment: Нашел как сделать эмуляцию нажатий через AutoHotkey.Interop, но наверняка есть более элегантный способ это сделать

Comment: `Может как-то можно подписаться на изменение содержимого буфера?` это вы в шутку заставили меня полвечера ответ писать? Этот вопрос читается вполне однозначно. Если считаете ответ полезным, то можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа. Если у вас другой вопрос - задайте его отдельно. Здесь есть правило: один вопрос - один ответ, не допускается несколько вопросов на 1 пост. Если ваш вопрос только про генерацию нажатия клавиш - то он дубликат, потому что такой ответ [уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1403446/373567), вы просто не очень внимательно искали.

Comment: Отметите ответ принятым? Жалко удалять, вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: нет, нет, ответ полезен и я его использовал. Спасибо большое - ответил как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Как отслеживать изменение буфера обмена в WPF

Самый простой вариант отслеживания изменения буфера обмена - Windows сообщение [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate). Это сообщение поддерживается начиная с Windows Vista, для более старых версий Windows потребуется другая реализация для устаревшего Windows сообщения `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`, она будет выглядеть немного посложнее.

Потребуется вот такой класс

```
public sealed class ClipboardMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
    private readonly HwndSourceHook _hook;
    private readonly HwndSource _hwndSource;
    private bool _disposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Возникает в случае, если содержимое буфера обмена изменилось.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ClipboardChanged;

    public ClipboardMonitor(HwndSource hwndSource)
    {
        _hwndSource = hwndSource ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hwndSource));
        if (!NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(_hwndSource.Handle))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        _hook = WndProc;
        _hwndSource.AddHook(_hook);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
                ClipboardChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                handled = true;
                break;
            default:
                handled = false;
                break;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        _disposed = true;
        if (disposing)
            _hwndSource.RemoveHook(_hook);
        if (!NativeMethods.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(_hwndSource.Handle) && disposing)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    ~ClipboardMonitor() => Dispose(false);
}
```

**Win API**

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
}
```

Экземпляр этого класса следует создать после инициализации окна, и уничтожать при закрытии окна.

**События**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        ...
        SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

**Обработчики**

```
private ClipboardMonitor _cm;

private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HwndSource hwnd = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    _cm = new ClipboardMonitor(hwnd);
    _cm.ClipboardChanged += OnClipboardChanged;
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _cm.Dispose();
}

private void OnClipboardChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // буфер обмена изменился
}
```

Вместо `Window.SourceInitialized` можно использовать событие `Window.Loaded`, зависит от ваших требований к решению. `SourceInitialized` возникает раньше, и это самое раннее событие, где можно успешно получить `HwndSource`.