# Как узнать, какие приложения изменяли буфер обмена

Tags: c#, clipboard

Вопрос состоит в том, что скорее всего у меня стоит какой-то вирус, который меняет адрес кошелька при копировании в буфере обмена. Можно ли как-то просмотреть лог буфера обмена, например какой процесс изменял?

Искал инфу по классу ClipBoard на C# так как он отвечает за буфер, но ничего нужного не нашел

Comment: Поставьте касперского, просканируйтесь. Вообще отслеживать изменения в буфере можно, но узнать какое приложение это сделало, насколько мне известно, не получится. Только сам факт изменения [можно отследить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1442172/373567).

Comment: @aepot, возможно почти всё, главное что это может быть несуразно. Так, можно поставить хук на каждый поток каждого не системного процесса и тогда вы будете получать имя процесса и данные, которые он сунул в буфер обмена. Но я думаю, что под драйвера такого решения нет.