# Обработка сообщений Windows Hook. Обработать сообщение от другой программы

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, maui

Имеется программа, рассылающая сообщения на c++.

[image: Сообщение]

В WPF принимаю следующим образом:

```cs
public static void RegisterWindowMessage(this Window window, string lpString, Action<string> action)
{
    _action = action;
    _msg = RegisterWindowMessage(lpString);
    var source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
    source?.AddHook(WndProc);
}
```

И обработка Hook:

```cs
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == _msg)
    {
        _action(lParam.ToString());
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Возникла задача перенести проект на MAUI. Соответственно решил сделать тоже самое через WinApi:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, IntPtr dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThreadId();

public static void RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString, Action<string> action)
{
     _action = action;
     _msg = RegisterWindowMessage(lpString.ToString()); //49824

      HoockProc = new HookProc(HookCallback);

      ProcessModule module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
      IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);

      IntPtr hwnd = ((MauiWinUIWindow)App.Current.Windows[0].Handler.PlatformView).WindowHandle;

      MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
      {
          var WH_MSGFILTER = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_MSGFILTER, HoockProc);
          var WH_MSGFILTERErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_CALLWNDPROC = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_CALLWNDPROC, HoockProc);
          var WH_CALLWNDPROCErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, HoockProc);
          var WH_CALLWNDPROCRETErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_KEYBOARD = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_KEYBOARD, HoockProc);
          var WH_KEYBOARDErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_KEYBOARD_LL = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HoockProc, false);
          var WH_KEYBOARD_LLErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_MOUSE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_MOUSE, HoockProc);
          var WH_MOUSE_ErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_MOUSE_LL = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_MOUSE_LL, HoockProc, false);
          var WH_MOUSE_LLErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_JOURNALRECORD = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_JOURNALRECORD, HoockProc, false);//
          var WH_JOURNALRECORDErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK, HoockProc, false);//
          var WH_JOURNALPLAYBACKErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE, HoockProc);
          var WH_FOREGROUNDIDLEKErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_SYSMSGFILTER = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_SYSMSGFILTER, HoockProc, false, false);//
          var WH_SYSMSGFILTERErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_GETMESSAGE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_GETMESSAGE, HoockProc);
          var WH_GETMESSAGEErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_CBT = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_CBT, HoockProc);
          var WH_CBTErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_HARDWARE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_HARDWARE, HoockProc);
          var WH_HARDWAREErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_DEBUG = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_DEBUG, HoockProc);
          var WH_DEBUGErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          var WH_SHELL = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_SHELL, HoockProc);
          var WH_SHELLErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      });


      //_hookId = SetWindowsHookEx((int)HookTypes.WH_GETMESSAGE, HoockProc, nint.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
}


        #endregion

    private static IntPtr SetHook(HookTypes typeOfHook, HookProc callBack, bool onThread = true, bool onDescriptor = false)
        {
            IntPtr hwnd = ((MauiWinUIWindow)App.Current.Windows[0].Handler.PlatformView).WindowHandle;

            var descriptor = onDescriptor ? hwnd : IntPtr.Zero;
            var thread = onThread ? GetCurrentThreadId() : nint.Zero;

            return SetWindowsHookEx((int)typeOfHook, callBack, descriptor, thread);

            //IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule currentModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
            {
                if (onThread)
                    return SetWindowsHookEx((int)typeOfHook, callBack, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
                else
                    return SetWindowsHookEx((int)typeOfHook, callBack, 0, 0);
                    //return SetWindowsHookEx((int)typeOfHook, callBack, GetModuleHandle(currentModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }
 }

private static IntPtr HookCallback(IntPtr hwnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    // Ваш обработчик сообщений

    Debug.WriteLine($"{hwnd} - {message} - {lParam} - {wParam}");

   //_action?.Invoke(message);

   return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Вывод в debug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обрабатывает сообщения мыши, клавиатуры, работу с окном, но не видит этих сообщений.

Как можно изменить код, чтобы прилетели сообщения?

Comment: Проблема в отправке, а не в приёме. Не туда отправляете. А вообще можно WM не использовать в принципе, это громоздско и неудобно. Используйте например [Named Pipe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567) для обмена данными между приложениями.

Comment: Кстати, в WPF оно как-то проще делалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1442172/373567, в смысле навешивание своего обработчика на WM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал это с помощью WinAPI, создав пустое невидимое окно внутри Maui Blazor.

```cs
internal class Win32
{
    public const uint WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
    public const uint WM_CREATE = 0x0001;
    public const uint WM_PAINT = 0x000F;

    public const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
    public const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
    public const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
    public const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
    public const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
    public const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
    public const uint WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    public const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW =
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU 
|       WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

    public const uint IDI_APPLICATION = 32512;

    public const uint IDC_ARROW = 32512;

    public const uint COLOR_WINDOW = 5;

    public const uint MB_OK = 0x00000000;
    public const uint MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = 0x00000030;
    public const uint MB_SETFOREGROUND = 0x00010000;

    //public const uint CW_USEDEFAULT = 0x80000000;

    public delegate IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    /*
    public enum GetWindowLongConst
    {
        GWL_WNDPROC = (-4),
        GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6),
        GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8),
        GWL_STYLE = (-16),
        GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20),
        GWL_USERDATA = (-21),
        GWL_ID = (-12)
    }
     * */

    [Flags]
    public enum ClassStyles : uint
    {
        ByteAlignClient = 0x1000,
        ByteAlignWindow = 0x2000,
        ClassDC = 0x40,
        DoubleClicks = 0x8,
        DropShadow = 0x20000,
        GlobalClass = 0x4000,
        HorizontalRedraw = 0x2,
        NoClose = 0x200,
        OwnDC = 0x20,
        ParentDC = 0x80,
        SaveBits = 0x800,
        VerticalRedraw = 0x1
    }

    public enum MessageBoxResult : uint
    {
        Ok = 1,
        Cancel,
        Abort,
        Retry,
        Ignore,
        Yes,
        No,
        Close,
        Help,
        TryAgain,
        Continue,
        Timeout = 32000
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SIZE
    {
        public int cx;
        public int cy;

        public SIZE(int cx, int cy)
        {
            this.cx = cx;
            this.cy = cy;
        }
    }

    public struct MSG
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public uint message;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public uint time;
        public POINT pt;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PAINTSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr hdc;
        public bool fErase;
        public RECT rcPaint;
        public bool fRestore;
        public bool fIncUpdate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public byte[] rgbReserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WNDCLASSEX
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public ClassStyles style;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public WndProc lpfnWndProc;
        public int cbClsExtra;
        public int cbWndExtra;
        public IntPtr hInstance;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public IntPtr hCursor;
        public IntPtr hbrBackground;
        public string lpszMenuName;
        public string lpszClassName;
        public IntPtr hIconSm;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern sbyte GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin,
       uint wMsgFilterMax);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage(ref MSG lpmsg);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool TranslateMessage(ref MSG lpMsg);

    //[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]       // 32 bits only
    //public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr BeginPaint(IntPtr hwnd, out PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EndPaint(IntPtr hWnd, ref PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void PostQuitMessage(int nExitCode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadIcon(IntPtr hInstance, IntPtr lpIconName);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern MessageBoxResult MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, string text, string caption, int options);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
       uint dwExStyle,
       string lpClassName,
       string lpWindowName,
       uint dwStyle,
       int x,
       int y,
       int nWidth,
       int nHeight,
       IntPtr hWndParent,
       IntPtr hMenu,
       IntPtr hInstance,
       IntPtr lpParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern short RegisterClassEx(ref WNDCLASSEX lpwcx);

    //[DllImport("gdi.dll")]
    //public static extern bool GetTextExtentPoint(IntPtr hdc, string lpString, int cbString, out SIZE lpSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool TextOut(IntPtr hdc, int nXStart, int nYStart,
       string lpString, int cbString);

    //[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    //public static extern bool GetTextMetrics(IntPtr hdc, out TEXTMETRIC lptm);
}

internal static class WindowExtensions
{

    #region Private static fields

    private static Action<nint> _action;
    private static uint _msgId;

    #endregion

    private static readonly string AppName = "DrawHello Program";
    private static readonly string ClassName = "DrawHelloClass";
    private static IntPtr hWnd;

    #region Public methods

    public static void RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString, Action<nint> action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _msgId = Win32.RegisterWindowMessage(lpString.ToString());

        WNDCLASSEX wcex = new()
        {
            style = ClassStyles.DoubleClicks
        };
        wcex.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(wcex);
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
        //wcex.hIcon = Win32.LoadIcon(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)Win32.IDI_APPLICATION);
        //wcex.hCursor = Win32.LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)Win32.IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;
        //wcex.hbrBackground = (IntPtr)(Win32.COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wcex.lpszMenuName = null;
        wcex.lpszClassName = ClassName;
   
        if (RegisterClassEx(ref wcex) == 0)
        {
            _ = MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "RegisterClassEx failed", AppName,
                (int)(MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND));
            return;
        }

        //uint visible = Win32.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | Win32.WS_VISIBLE;
        uint invisible = 0;

        var x = 0; // 250;
        var y = 0; // 250;
        var w = 0; // 250;
        var h = 0; // 250;
        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName, AppName, invisible,
            x, y, w, h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            _ = MessageBox(
                IntPtr.Zero, "CreateWindow failed", AppName, 
                (int)(Win32.MB_OK | Win32.MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | Win32.MB_SETFOREGROUND));
            return;
        }

        // Main message loop:
        /*int rv;
        while ((rv = GetMessage(out MSG Msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) > 0)
        {
            _ = Win32.TranslateMessage(ref Msg);
            _ = Win32.DispatchMessage(ref Msg);
        }*/
    }

    private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (message == _msgId)
        {
            _action?.Invoke(lParam);
        }
        switch (message)
        {
            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```