# Проблема с установкой фонового изображения в WPF из буфера обмена

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net, .net-7

Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке установки изображения из буфера обмена. Вот минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы.

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _ = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback((_) => 
            {               
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                {
                    if (Clipboard.ContainsImage() is true) 
                    {
                        BitmapSource image = Clipboard.GetImage();

                        this.Background = new ImageBrush(image);
                    }
                });
            }), null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```

Ожидаемой поведение - любое изображение из буфера обмена windows должно стать фоном окна.

По факту если мы используем к примеру инструмент ms-screenclip:, тот что вызывается комбинацией горячих клавиш Win + Shift + S в Windows 10, изображение становится фоном окна.
Если же открыть в Paint изображение, и попытаться скопировать область изображения, то вместо фона, в wpf окне, всё заливается чёрным цветом.
Например из Paint в фотошоп нормально копируется.

Метаданные изображения вроде одинаковые, ну кроме размера самого изображения.

Comment: Решение однозначно рабочее. Просто я ещё в процессе алгоритма дешифровки DIB разбираюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень интересная задачка оказалась. Дело в том, что Paint в буфер обмена загоняет картинку только в формате DIB (Device Independent Bitmap), который несовместим с .NET оберткой буфера. Возможно через COM можно как-то его заставить преобразовать данные во что-то другое, но напрямую ничего подобного в буфере нет, и у меня не получилось достать. Так что на гениальность не претендую.

Я нашел [древнее решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424800/12888024) и немного переписал, выбросив лишнее. Для работы класса требуется установка NuGet пакета **System.Drawing.Common**.

**Получился вот такой конвертер**

```
public static class ClipboardDibConverter
{
    public const string Dib = "DeviceIndependentBitmap";

    public static MemoryStream ConvertToPng(MemoryStream ms)
    {
        if (ms == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ms));
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes = ms.ToArray();

        int headerSize = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(bytes);
        // Only supporting 40-byte DIB from clipboard
        if (headerSize != 40)
            throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported DIB header size");
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> header = bytes[..headerSize];
        int dataOffset = headerSize;
        int width = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(header[0x04..]);
        int height = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(header[0x08..]);
        short planes = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16LittleEndian(header[0x0C..]);
        short bitCount = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16LittleEndian(header[0x0E..]);
        //Compression: 0 = RGB; 3 = BITFIELDS.
        int compression = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(header[0x10..]);
        // Not dealing with non-standard formats.
        if (planes != 1 || (compression != 0 && compression != 3))
            throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported DIB compression type");
        PixelFormat fmt = bitCount switch
        {
            32 => PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb,
            24 => PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb,
            16 => PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555,
            _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported DIB pixel format")
        };
        if (compression == 3)
            dataOffset += 12;
        if (bytes.Length < dataOffset)
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong DIB image data length");
        byte[] image = bytes[dataOffset..].ToArray();
        if (compression == 3)
        {
            uint redMask = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(bytes[headerSize..]);
            uint greenMask = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(bytes[(headerSize + 4)..]);
            uint blueMask = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(bytes[(headerSize + 8)..]);

            if (bitCount == 32 && redMask == 0xFF0000 && greenMask == 0x00FF00 && blueMask == 0x0000FF)
            {
                for (int pix = 3; pix < image.Length; pix += 4)
                {
                    if (image[pix] != 0)
                    {
                        fmt = PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported DIB pixel bitmask format");
        }
        using Bitmap bmp = CreateBitmap(image, width, height, fmt);
        bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
        MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(result, ImageFormat.Png);
        return result;
    }

    private static Bitmap CreateBitmap(byte[] bytes, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, bmpData.Scan0, height * bmpData.Stride);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Далее, я не понял, что делает ваш таймер, наверное просто ждет 10 секунд и хватает буфер обмена. Это было неудобно, поэтому я взял ранее написанный мной [монитор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1442172/373567), и написал немного другой пример.

**Монитор буфера обмена**

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
}
```

```
public sealed class ClipboardMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
    private readonly HwndSourceHook _hook;
    private readonly HwndSource _hwndSource;
    private bool _disposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Возникает в случае, если содержимое буфера обмена изменилось.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ClipboardChanged;

    public ClipboardMonitor(HwndSource hwndSource)
    {
        _hwndSource = hwndSource ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hwndSource));
        if (!NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(_hwndSource.Handle))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        _hook = WndProc;
        _hwndSource.AddHook(_hook);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
                ClipboardChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                handled = true;
                break;
            default:
                handled = false;
                break;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        _disposed = true;
        if (disposing)
            _hwndSource.RemoveHook(_hook);
        if (!NativeMethods.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(_hwndSource.Handle) && disposing)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    ~ClipboardMonitor() => Dispose(false);
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppClipImage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppClipImage"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
</Window>
```

**Кодбихайнд**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ClipboardMonitor _monitor;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceInitialized += MainWindow_SourceInitialized;
        Closing += MainWindow_Closing;            
    }

    private void MainWindow_SourceInitialized(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource hwnd = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
        _monitor = new ClipboardMonitor(hwnd);
        _monitor.ClipboardChanged += OnClipboardChanged;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _monitor?.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnClipboardChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            string[] formats = obj.GetFormats(false);
            if (formats.Contains(ClipboardDibConverter.Dib, StringComparer.Ordinal))
            {
                object data = obj.GetData(ClipboardDibConverter.Dib, false);
                if (data is MemoryStream ms)
                {
                    MemoryStream png = ClipboardDibConverter.ConvertToPng(ms);
                    BitmapImage image = BitmapImageFromStream(png);
                    Background = new ImageBrush(image);
                }
            }
            else if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                object data = obj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                if (data is BitmapSource src)
                {
                    Background = new ImageBrush(src);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(ex.Message, ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static BitmapImage BitmapImageFromStream(MemoryStream ms)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Вся суть ответа в методе `OnClipboardChanged`. Если в буфере обмена DIB, то беру его, в противном случае использую ваш метод из вопроса.

*Кстати, при попытке прочитать буфер обмена, может вывалиться исключение о том, что буфер обмена не получилось открыть, это нормально, в таких случаях надо попытаться еще раз. Я обычно такое исключение ловлю в цикле и пытаюсь примерно 10 попыток раз в 50мс, и если все равно не удалось, то выбрасываю наверх последнее. Такое исключение случается не часто, но по-другому его не объехать.*